# What does the "j-= 1" do in this insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, python-3.5

I am following how to implement an insertion sort algorithm in python3 from a tutorial but I cant seem to understand why it is "j -= 1" in this code and not j += 1.

```
sample1 = [5,3,2,4,6]

def insertion_sort(sample):
    print("initial sample: ",sample)

    for i in range(1,len(sample)):
        j = i
        while(j!=0 and sample[j] < sample[j-1]):
            sample[j-1],sample[j] = sample[j],sample[j-1]
            j -= 1   #why this and not j += 1 instead?
    print("sorted sample: ",sample)
```

insertion_sort(sample1)

Comment: Because j _decreases_ from i down to 0, not _increases_ from 0 up to i.

Comment: But if i begins at 1 from the for-loop, wont it make the next iteration of j = 0?

Comment: For `i = 1`, yes. For `i = 2`, the first thing is to set `j = 1`. For `i = 10`, the first thing is to set `j = 9`.

Answer (score 0):

Because j starts from the value of i and goes down to 0.

If you would increase j by 1 -as you wanted to do- your j would never ever reach 0 so the j!=0 in your while loop would be true  all the time , what means infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Example of Insertion sort:
[image]
As you can see, insertion sort starts from the 2nd element unlike selection sort. So you start at the continue increasing `i` and reducing `j` from position `i` till `0`. Hence in the `i`th permutation, you are bringing the lowest element you find to the first place and creating a sorted array of size `i`

```
def insertion_sort(sample):
    print("initial sample: ",sample)

    for i in range(1,len(sample)):
        j = i #start from i and run till 0.
        while(j!=0 and sample[j] < sample[j-1]):
            sample[j-1],sample[j] = sample[j],sample[j-1] #swapping if element j-1 > element j to get lowest element on 1st place.
            j -= 1   #from element i to element 0
    print("sorted sample: ",sample)
```